# Create $(<div/>) Jquery into pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to create this Jquery code into pure javascript

```
let container = $('body');

let cursor = $('<div/>').addClass('cursor').html('<svg/></svg>').appendTo(container);
```

But I got confused when creating a pure javascript selector for this type of selection method from jquery

```
$('<div/>')
```

When i try to console **`$('<div/>')`** then the output

```
w.fn.init [div]
 0: div
  length: 1
 [[Prototype]]: Object(0)
```

*Could someone help me to create this jquery code into pure js code*

Comment: `<svg/></svg>` seems bad syntax.

Comment: The OP wants to convert jQuery to vanilla JS @YuvrajMule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Cache the container
const container = document.querySelector('body');

// Create a new element
const cursor = document.createElement('div');

// Add the className, and innerHTML
cursor.className = 'cursor';
cursor.innerHTML = '<svg></svg>';

// Append it to the container
container.appendChild(cursor);
```

```css
.cursor { border: 1px solid black; height: 100px; width: 100px; }
```

Additional documentation

- [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
- [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className)
- [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)
- [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)